# Usage: derogatory + towards + X

Tags: word-usage

Came across this sentence today"

> "I've never been derogatory towards taxi drivers," he said.

from the BBC's, [**Uber boss Travis Kalanick: I'm no bully**](http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-29475059).

Can one really be derogatory *towards* something?!

Sounds wrong to me.

Comment: Use *of* or *about* instead. The adjective does not take the preposition *towards* by nature of its meaning. However, it is not ungrammatical or incorrect to use *towards* in a suitable context.

Comment: Note that the statement is attributed to the person interviewed, not the BBC. As such it does not have to be grammatically very correct.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a question on which British English and U.S. English differ. In any event, *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) has this entry for *derogatory*:

> **derogatory** *adj* (ca. 1503) **1 :** detracting from the character or standing of something — often used with *to*, *towards*, or *of* **2 :** expressive of a low opinion : DISPARAGING {*derogatory* remarks}

I have frequently seen and heard *derogatory* coupled with *to* or *toward(s)*, as in the sentence "That book is derogatory toward women." In everyday U.S. usage, I suspect, *derogatory* has become almost interchangeable with *disparaging*.

---

**UPDATE (12/10/14): *Examples of 'derogatory toward' and 'derogatory towards'***

A Google Books search finds a number of published instances, from the 1930s forward, in which a speech, text, or other thing is said to be derogatory toward (or towards) someone or something. From [*American Beef Producer*](https://books.google.com/books?id=mJBOAAAAYAAJ&q=%22is+derogatory+toward%22&dq=%22is+derogatory+toward%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rzyJVPm2FcOsogTU14DgAg&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA) (1931) [combined snippets]:

> What about research? Dr. Breimyer discussed the factors involved, and then called attention to "the publication policies of the department that seem to be directed mainly to ensuring that nothing shall be released that **is derogatory toward** the department's operating programs or policy stands."

And from Shelby McCloy, [*Gibbon's Antagonism to Christianity ... and the Discussions It Has Provoked*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZxMHAQAAIAAJ&q=%22is+derogatory+toward%22&dq=%22is+derogatory+toward%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PDuJVMT7CNDloAT5zYDADg&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA) (1933) [combined snippets]:

> He [Milner] makes an assault upon Gibbon's treatment of the Gnostics, in part because he feels it **is derogatory toward** the Old Testament. He quotes Gibbon as saying that the Gnostics held the Mosaic accounts of the creation and of the fall of man in derision, and he flatly denies that this was the case, citing the authority of Irenæus and Mosheim.

Instances in which a person is said to be derogatory in the same way are somewhat rarer, but they do exist. From [*Elementary English*](https://books.google.com/books?id=rn63AAAAIAAJ&q=%22are+derogatory+toward%22&dq=%22are+derogatory+toward%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aDGJVMevHcy7ogT2lYGoDg&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ), volume 8, issue 2 (1971) [combined snippets]:

> An effort should be made to withhold tenure from those teachers who overtly or covertly **are derogatory toward** such dialect. Inservice programs in psycholinguistics should be developed for teachers already employed in urban schools.

From Kevin Ryerson, [*Spirit Communication: The Soul's Path*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22are+derogatory+toward+any+of+your+brothers%22) (1989) [combined snippets]:

> What is God? God is the interlinking of yourself with the whole. It is from the whole that the inner light comes.So, if you **are derogatory toward** any of your brothers or sisters, then you are derogatory toward yourself, and that light grows dim, for you have disinherited a small portion of yourself.

And from William Marshall, [*Sexual Offender Treatment: Controversial Issues*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ulJCFft9530C&pg=PA190&dq=are+derogatory+toward+their+victims&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wDiJVOb4KpSJoQSHgYGYAQ&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=are%20derogatory%20toward%20their%20victims&f=false) (2005):

> Controlling anger and hostility may be even more difficult when clients are entrenched in cognitive distortions, maintaining a victim stance, **are derogatory toward** their victims or very negative toward treatment. However, therapists should note that expression of their negative feelings can have a detrimental impact on therapy.

Answer (score 0):

A *person* is never derogatory, but his *words* may be.

He should have said something like this:

"I've never spoken about taxi drivers in a derogatory manner."

Answer (score 0):

He may have meant "denigratory", which would have been appropriate with 'towards'.

Answer (score 0):

A less strange-sounding alternative in this case might be "I've never been derogative of taxi drivers".